# kubernetes v1.14.2 newly creation pod not coming up

Tags: linux, kubernetes

Creating cassandra configuration in kubernetes v1.14.2 version. 
New pod is not coming up still it is in pending status.
I've tried below command still not coming up.

```
kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')"

[root@master cassandra_dc]# kubectl get events --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON                   OBJECT                                 MESSAGE
c7a           3m49s       Warning   FailedScheduling         pod/cassandraa-0                       0/4 nodes are available: 4 node(s) didn't match node selector.
c7a           3m49s       Warning   FailedScheduling         pod/cassandrab-0                       0/4 nodes are available: 4 node(s) didn't match node selector.
kube-system   65s         Normal    SandboxChanged           pod/cilium-operator-854d87d765-qk6ct   Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
kube-system   15m         Warning   FailedCreatePodSandBox   pod/cilium-operator-854d87d765-qk6ct   (combined from similar events): Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "2e20efe9ec5e3d857de7052cf0df43556d01b48889566450e6392262bf7546d8" network for pod "cilium-operator-854d87d765-qk6ct": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "cilium-operator-854d87d765-qk6ct_kube-system" network: unable to connect to Cilium daemon: failed to create cilium agent client after 30.000000 seconds timeout: Get http://%!F(MISSING)var%!F(MISSING)run%!F(MISSING)cilium%!F(MISSING)cilium.sock/v1/config: dial unix /var/run/cilium/cilium.sock: connect: no such file or directory

[root@master cassandra_dc]# kubectl get nodes
NAME                     STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION
master.localdomain.com   Ready    master   113m   v1.14.2
slave1.localdomain.com   Ready    node     112m   v1.14.2
slave2.localdomain.com   Ready    node     112m   v1.14.2
slave3.localdomain.com   Ready    node     112m   v1.14.2
[root@master cassandra_dc]# kubectl -n c7a get pods -o wide
NAME           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP       NODE     NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
cassandraa-0   0/1     Pending   0          91m   <none>   <none>   <none>           <none>
cassandrab-0   0/1     Pending   0          91m   <none>   <none>   <none>           <none>
```

Comment: I added a code block for your terminal text to make it readable.